# how to make a selection based on multiple negative criteria?

Tags: jquery

I already filtered a `select` element for non multiple selects :

```
$("select:not([multiple])").select2().on("change", function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).parent().find("span[role='combobox']").each(function() {
           $(this).attr("data-validate-func", "required").attr("data-validate-hint", "<?php echo _getText('global.champ.obligatoire'); ?>");
      });
    } else {
      $(this).parent().find("span[role='combobox']").each(function() {
           $(this).removeAttr("data-validate-func");
      });
    }
});
```

Now I want to filter also for `select` elements not having a `Label` as its first `parent`. How to modify my code for that purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.filter()`:

```
$("select:not([multiple])").filter(function(){
    return $(this).parent().is('label')
}).select2().....
```

Comment: as from the documentation e1 is the index of the element , isnt'it ?

Comment: @pheromix yeah true.

Comment: I got console error `missing ) after argument list`

Comment: I found the cause : I added this to the argument of select2 : `width: "100%"` , it gave me console error , so what is wrong ?

Comment: @pheromix i guess you want to add this way:  `.select2({width:"100%"})`

Comment: ohhhhh yes , i didnt look carefully at the examples , omg ! thx

Answer (score 1):

You can add a descendant selector to your `:not` clause:

```
$("select:not([multiple], label > select)").select2().on("change", //...
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/17m03r9f/)

Comment: some select elements which have not label as parent are not rendered as select2 !

Comment: Ok. Without seeing any of your HTML it's going to be hard/impossible to diagnose.

Comment: I found the cause : I added this to the argument of select2 : `width: "100%"` , it gave me console error , so what is wrong ?